# The opposite of lexical this

Tags: javascript

This is a question about terminology.

Considering that there is a method that uses lexical `this`:

```
var foo = {
  method: function () {
    console.log(this, ' is the context');
  }
};

foo.method();
```

What's the conventional term for `this` when the method is called when being bound to different context or detached?

```
bazThatAcceptsACallback(foo.method);
foo.method.bind(baz)();
(0, foo.method)();
```

I often refer to it as 'non-lexical this' or 'contextual this' in such cases, but I never met these or similar terms in official or trusted sources.

Comment: How is this "lexical `this`"?

Comment: The wording could do with some more clarification here. Do you mean what the word is for the scope in which the function was defined (e.g. `foo` in this case) versus the context under which it is called (`this` which may or may not refer to `foo`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite of lexical `this` is [*dynamic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping) `this`.

However, notice that lexical `this` is not what you have shown in your `function` snippet, it's the `this` that arrow functions have.

Comment: Thanks, opposing dynamic scope to static scope makes perfect sense here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need different terms to describe the behavior of JS lexical `this` for what it is referring to. Its always the "context" the function is called in. Let it be the parent object or another binding - you can always say the lexical `this` represent the context.